# Как в alfresco search services 2.0.2 искать значение поля по точному совпадению?

Tags: запрос, search, solr, alfresco

В Alfresco Search Services 2.0 изменили поведение знака "="
Конкретнее тут https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-blog/exact-term-queries-in-search-services-2-0/ba-p/302200

Сейчас, если в запросе написать "=" то поиск вернет все вхождения термина, например, нужно найти "Слон", поиск вернет "Розовый слон", "Красный слон" и т.д. В версии 1.4.0 поиск вернул бы точное совпадение.
Как сейчас в версии 2.0.2 нужно написать поисковый запрос, чтобы поиск возвращал точное совпадение со словом "Слон", подскажите, пожалуйста?